# What is the meaning of "/."?

Tags: replacement, syntax

I've looked to the built-in help of *Mathematica*, but I still can't understand the usage of `/.`, like in the following expression:

```
mytangent[f_, x_, p_] := (f'[x] /. x -> p) (x - p) + f[p]
```

If `/.` just means that `p` replaces `x`, why don't write directly `f'[p]`, etc?

Comment: There are many cases where you have to use `ReplaceAll` which is what `/.` is shorthand for.  In this case you can use `f'[t]` easily though

Comment: Evaluate this: `?/.` in Mma and you will see the hint.

Answer (score 10):

To be very explicit and related to the situation in your question, consider this simple function `f` and the different `fs` that all *might* be ways to compute the derivative at a first glance.

```
ClearAll[f, fs, fs2, fs3, fs4];
f[x_] := x^2;
fs[x_] := D[f[x], x];
fs2[x_] := f'[x];
fs3[x_] = D[f[x], x];
fs4[x_] := Block[{t}, D[f[t], t] /. t -> x];
```

Let's check what happens if we want to know the derivative at `x=3`.

```
fs[3]
```

> General::ivar: 3 is not a valid variable. >>
>       fs2[3]
>       (* 6 *)
>       fs3[3]
>       (* 6 *)
>       fs4[3]
>       (* 6 *)

So we observe, everything except `fs` works well. But what is wrong with `fs`? Let us have a look at this:

```
Trace[fs[3]]
(* {fs[3],D[f[3],3],{f[3],3^2,9},D[9,3],...} *)
```

What happens is that Mathematica wants to take the derivative of the value `f[3]` which is `9` with respect to its argument `3`. Clearly, this doesn't make any sense, so there's the `General::ivar` error.

A "fix" is to use any of the three other approaches:

- `fs2` is how you have it in your question. Mathematica takes care of the order of evaluation internally, so here no need to use `ReplaceAll`, as mentioned in the comments. You can also inspect `Trace[fs2[3]]` to see why.
- `fs3` uses `Set` instead of `SetDelayed` in contrast to `fs`. This means, it evaluates the derivative once, and then just plugs in values for `x`.
- `fs4` demonstrates how you can use `ReplaceAll` in order to obtain the derivative via a `SetDelayed` definition and using a form like in `fs`. Here, you take the derivative w.r.t. the local symbol `t` (hence the `Block`) and then afterwards insert the value of interest using `/.`.

As a sidenode, `fs3` evaluates roughly an order of magnitude faster than the others since it has already computed the derivative and only needs to compute its value at the given position.

Answer (score 1):

See [ReplaceAll](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) and [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/25616#25616).

Say you want to find a root, you would code something like

```
rule = FindRoot[x^3 - Tanh[x], {x, 1.0, 1.2}]
```

and get as result:

> {x -> 0.893395}

Next step ist (as proposed by @Alexei Boulbitch)

> expr/.rules applies a rule or list of rules in an attempt to transform
>   each subpart of an expression expr.  >>

```
soln = x /. rule
```

> 0.893395

And use it like so:

```
Plot[x^3 - Tanh[x], {x, 0, 1}, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point@{soln, 0}}]
```

[image]