# NDSolve How do I insert another boundry condition

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration

So I'm new to programming and I am trying to solve a very simple differential equation (i can do this by hand but the thing is i can't program it), the equation is `a'[t] == - 0.0118`, with the boundary conditions `a[0]==3` and I want to know `a[180]=?`, how do I insert this (a[180]=?) into the code, this is my short code.

```
Sol = NDSolve[{a'[t] == -0.0118 , a[0] == 3 }, a, {t, 0, 180}]
Plot[Sol, {t, 0, 180}]
```

It doesn't show anything in the plot

Thanks a lot, any type of help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are practically there already. Observe that you are plotting the solution in the way you wrote the code. What you actually want to do, is to plot the function `a[t]` evaluated on the solution of the `NDSolve`

So, we have

```
Sol = NDSolve[{a'[t] == -0.0118, a[0] == 3}, a, {t, 0, 180}]
Plot[a[t] /. Sol, {t, 0, 180}]
```

This is the main thing that you want to notice: `a[t] /. Sol`

By that logic you can use

```
a[t] /. Sol /. t -> 180
```

to read the value at the point you want.

Comment: Thank you so much, but what does /. mean?

Comment: Hi, it is the way to tell mathematica to apply a rule or a list o rules on an expression. You can find more details here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/113306/what-is-the-meaning-of/113314 or you can just evaluate ?/. in a mathematica notebook to learn more

Comment: @Sosa, whenever you encounter a mysterious symbol in *Mathematica* code, highlight it in the notebook you are using, and press F1.